# Браузер выдаёт предупреждение об устаревшей функции (jPlayer.js)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Собственно, вот само предупреждение:

> A page or script is accessing at least one of navigator.userAgent,
> navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform. Starting in Chrome 101,
> the amount of information available in the User Agent string will be
> reduced. To fix this issue, replace the usage of navigator.userAgent,
> navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform with feature detection,
> progressive enhancement, or migrate to navigator.userAgentData. Note
> that for performance reasons, only the first access to one of the
> properties is shown.

Посмотрел код плеера, ужаснулся количеству строк и закрыл :D
Ошибка как бы не смертельная, на работу не влияет, но всё же хотелось, чтобы всё было без предупреждений.
jPlayer.org не обновляется с 2014 года, однако остаётся лучшим мульти-браузерным решением для стриминг трансляций.
Может кто делал себе апгрейд патч или есть где-то github комьюнити? Буду благодарен!

Comment: Переведите код ошибки на русский.

Comment: Вы используете `npm` или `cdn` ? — опишите шаги воспроизведения данной ошибки, на сайте проекта в демо ошибка не воспроизводится, если используете фреймворк тоже укажите